# Error when running selected line of code in VS Code

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, nameerror

I cannot run the selected block of the code in VS Code.

Given the code that works well if I run it as a whole

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(5)
print(x)
```

if I select the line `print(x)` and press `Shift+Enter`, it yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

It looks like the objects are erased from the memory as soon as the compilation is over.
Could somebody explain what is the reason and how to tackle this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, the previous objects are erased with every execution of the code from the memory.

When you run just the print statement, it is like you would just run `print(x)` in a new file without defining it.

To my knowledge, this can't be changed, because the python interpreter works that way, and it creates a temporary file with the selected code and runs that. In that file are the objects not defined, and thus it raises an exception.

Comment: thank you! But how could I run the selected line of code if I do not want to execute the whole script?

Comment: @Python It depends on the specific circumstance. depends on the logic of the code you are running.

Comment: @Python you could run in addition to the line the lines where you define the object.